# Why doesn't desktop-save-mode persist neotree?

Tags: window, desktop, persistence

Desktop-save-mode seems to save all windows *except* neotree - When I restart emacs, the neotree window is always gone. Why is this window different from the others? Is it possible for neotree's state to persist like everything else?

Comment: do you still need this? Try playing with `(defun desktop-save-buffer-p (&rest a) t)`